# Lebesgue Measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know that the n-dimensional Lebesgue-Measure $\lambda^n$ is defined at least on all Borel Sets $\mathcal{B}^n= \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let's assume $A=(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

(i) My first question is whether it is possible to define $\lambda^n(A)$? I suppose that this leads to $\lambda^n(A)=0$?

(ii) Is it allowed to use the 1-dimensional Lebesgue-Measure here or can we do no other than using $\lambda^n$ since the space is $\mathbb{R}^n$?

May anybody have an answer/explanation to this?

Comment: Notice that $(a,b)$ is not in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\geq 2$. However, if $n=2$, then  $\lambda ^n((a,b)\times \{0\})=0$. But maybe for you $(a,b)=\{a+t(b-a)\mid t\in (0,1)\}$ for $a,b\in \mathbb R^2$ and then indeed $\lambda ^n((a,b))=0$.

Comment: (i): No, it is not possible. (ii) No, this is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $(a,b)$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ for $n\ge 2$. Perhaps you want to embed $(a,b) \subset\Bbb R$ in $\Bbb R^n$ through a homeomorphism. In particular, you can consider the set $A' = (a,b) \times \underbrace{\{0\} \times \ldots \times \{0\}}_{n-1 \text{ times}} \subset \Bbb R^n$. $A$ and $A'$ are homeomorphic via the obvious map $f:A\to A', t \mapsto (t, 0, \ldots, 0)$.

1. Instead of $\lambda^n(A)$, it makes sense to find $\lambda^n(A')$. Indeed, $\lambda^n(A') = 0$.
2. No, you cannot use the one-dimensional Lebesgue measure here, since your set is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ (and not $\Bbb R$).

Comment: Thank you. Your construction of $A'$ is exactly what I meant, but failed to recognize that Intervals aren't subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thank you very much!